# Why is it called "Container Registry"?

Tags: kubernetes

I think the term "Container Registry" is misleading.

AFIAK the registry contains container **images**, not containers.

Why is it called "Container Registry"?

Comment: I can assume the term "image" is also widely known for defining pictures. And even in in virtualization world it's likely borrowed from "snapshot" idea, which also mean a picture made by a photo camera. "Image registry" is likely to be understood as a photo album with copyrighted pictures similar to USPTO. Therefore "container registry" is the closest available definition. "Registry" also has a similar term "repository" https://docs.docker.com/glossary/

Answer (score 1):

A **container registry** is a repository, or collection of repositories, used to store ***container images*** for Kubernetes, DevOps, and container-based application development.

The terms Image Registry and Container Registry are synonymous.

Comment: With other words: A container registry does not contain containers. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Right. It rather contains templates (=images, =filesystem snapshots) which defines an initial state of running containers. Although, running a container  also requires to define an environment for the container, like storage volumes, environment variables, desired cpu and memory size and sometimes custom command to run when container starts. That information isn't stored in registries.